# почему моя интернационализация не работает (SpringBoot Application)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Вот как я добавлял интернационализацию в моем приложении Spring.

Для начала я добавил в класс

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    // ...
}
```

метод (здесь я по дефолту ставлю русский язык):

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
    return slr;
}
```

Дальше в класс который реализует интерфейс `WebMvcConfigurer` я добавил два следующих метода:

```
@Component
public class WebMvcConfigurerImpl implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // ...

    // Конфигурация компонента, поддерживающего изменение настроек языка
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }


    // Регистрация компонента, поддерживающего изменение языка
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

После добавления кода, который указан выше я создал два файла `labels.properties` и `labels_en.properties` в папочке `resources`.
В этих файлах я в буду формате `key=value` записыть текст, который будет показыватся на страницах (я использую Thymeleaf).

Дальше нужно зарегистрировать эти файлы в приложении, для этого в файле `application.properties` я добавил название `labels` к `spring.messages.basename`, вот как это выглядит:

```
spring.messages.basename=errors-messages,labels
```

Теперь когда страница в запросе получает `...?lang=en` (параметр `lang` со значением `en`) то значение этикет на странице должно было бы сменится, но этого не происходит.

Что я сделал не так?